# Как сделать отправку данных с формы на почту?

Tags: php, email

```
if(isset($_POST['phone'])) {
    $phone = $_POST['phone'];

  mail("text@gmail.com", "subject", "$phone", "Content-type:text/plain; windows-1251");
```

поставил так но ничего не отправляется

Comment: Еще надо установить sendmail (а у него логи есть, на всякий), или вопросы к хостингу. Как альтернатива - phpMailer, для нее ничего ставить не надо, но нужно где-то создать ящик и использовать его в ней как отправителя.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скорее всего вы не установили нужные PHP расширения, либо на хостинге запрещена отправка сообщений на почту.